# Tuning alert Elastic SIEM (custom rule)

Tags: elasticsearch, exception, alert, rules

I have a custom rule in Elastic SIEM for http status code 404 and I want to add a exception for this alert because it generates many false positive. Does anyone have an idea how to tuning this alert?

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on your log information.

The first step i'd say is to determine what is the biggest shared property of the FP's. If for example you are only interested in 404's coming from the public ip ranges, i would suggest adding an exception on the `source.ip` with the private cidr ranges.